# How do I select the hours difference between the min start and max end of a given date period?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a simple problem, but I'm having a difficult time trying to formulate the proper SQL query to get this done. I've got a table that has multiple dates. Each date has multiple times. The times are in start - end increments that are manually added by the user.

```
+----+------------------+------------------+
| id | start            | end              |
+----+------------------+------------------+
|  6 | 2014/03/03 08:30 | 2014/03/03 09:00 |
|  7 | 2014/03/03 09:00 | 2014/03/03 11:15 |
|  8 | 2014/03/03 11:15 | 2014/03/03 11:45 |
|  9 | 2014/03/03 11:45 | 2014/03/03 12:45 |
| 10 | 2014/03/03 12:45 | 2014/03/03 13:15 |
| 11 | 2014/03/04 08:45 | 2014/03/04 09:00 |
| 12 | 2014/03/04 09:00 | 2014/03/04 13:00 |
| 13 | 2014/03/04 13:00 | 2014/03/04 13:30 |
| 14 | 2014/03/05 09:00 | 2014/03/05 09:30 |
| 15 | 2014/03/05 09:30 | 2014/03/05 12:30 |
| 16 | 2014/03/05 12:45 | 2014/03/05 12:45 |
| 19 | 2014/03/06 08:45 | 2014/03/06 09:00 |
| 20 | 2014/03/06 09:15 | 2014/03/06 10:00 |
```

I'm trying to calculate the difference in hours between the earliest start time and the latest end time per date.

Currently I'm just using a simple `unix_timestamp` conversion on my rows, however, it's only calculating the difference between the first row found, instead of the difference of all rows for a given date.

```
select
    unix_timestamp(min(start)) - unix_timestamp(max(end)) / 60.0 / 60.0 as hours_difference,
    min(start) as started,
    min(end) as ended              
from
    athlete_log
group by
    day(start)
```

The problem (as stated above) is that it only grabs the first row from a given date, such as:

```
| 6 | 2014/03/03 08:30 | 2014/03/03 09:00 |
```

But I need the earliest start time and the latest start time from:

```
|  6 | 2014/03/03 08:30 | 2014/03/03 09:00 |
|  7 | 2014/03/03 09:00 | 2014/03/03 11:15 |
|  8 | 2014/03/03 11:15 | 2014/03/03 11:45 |
|  9 | 2014/03/03 11:45 | 2014/03/03 12:45 |
| 10 | 2014/03/03 12:45 | 2014/03/03 13:15 |
```

Which should yield:

```
2014/03/03 8:30 - start
2014/03/03 13:15 - end
5.45 - hours_difference
```

But of course it's only selecting

```
2014/03/03 8:30 - start
2014/03/03 9:00 - end
.30 - hours_difference
```

How can I modify my query to select the min start and max end from a given date?

Comment: Why the conversion? Did you try `timediff` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've grouping on `DAY()`, which is probably incorrect. You only show data from March 2014 there, but if your DB actually has data from more months/years than just this, you'll be grouping togher 2014/03/03, 2014/02/03, 2013/02/03, etc.. (different years/months, same day-of-month)

You should be doing `GROUP BY DATE(start)`, so you group on the full `YYYY-MM-DD` date value.

Comment: Just tried it, unfortunately it didn't make any difference. :(

Comment: you're also selecting min(end) in the field list, shouldn't that max(end)?

Comment: That was the issue, it was the max.

Answer (score 1):

here's what you want

Updated: missed the group by first time around, try this

```
SELECT A.starter - A.ender, dates
FROM(
SELECT Min([start]) as starter
      ,Max([end]) as ender
      ,CONVERT (DATE, [start]) as dates
  FROM athlete_log
  Group By CONVERT (DATE, [start]) ) as A
```

if you just want the values you don't need the top select.  the inner select grabs the values the top level does the arithmeic.  if you have question feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly like this

```
SELECT started, ended, (unix_timestamp(ended) - unix_timestamp(started)) / (60.0 * 60.0)  as hours_difference
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE(start) AS start_date,
        MIN(start) as started,
        MAX(end) as ended              
    FROM athlete_log
    GROUP BY start_date
) Sub1;
```

which can be shortened to this

```
SELECT DATE(start) AS start_date,
    MIN(start) as started,
    MAX(end) as ended,
    (unix_timestamp(MAX(end)) - unix_timestamp(MIN(start))) / (60.0 * 60.0) as hours_difference
FROM athlete_log
GROUP BY start_date;
```

SQL fiddle here:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43757/7